# Unparseable date Exception on Unit Testing via Mockito

Tags: kotlin, unit-testing, mockito, simpledateformat, unparseable

In my case, i am in need of get the string date as format i prefer , below is the exact code i am using to get the return date as string

**Below is the Test Function:**

```
@Test
fun `get formatted server date`() {

    assertEquals(HelperFunctions.getFormattedServerDate("2024-01-05T06:00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ" ),"Fri Jan 05 11:30:00 GMT+05:30 2024")
}
```

And the getFormattedServerDate function is below as

```
fun getFormattedServerDate(date: String, dateFormat: String): Date? {
            val dateFormatter = SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat, Locale.US)
            dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")
            return dateFormatter.parse(date)
        }
```

On a run of the above code with input date as **2024-01-05T06:00:00** and format as **yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ** i get the output as **Fri Jan 05 11:30:00 GMT+05:30 2024** - Note: This happens in the realtime not in the Test case run
Exception:

```
Unparseable date: "2024-01-05T06:00:00+00:00"
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2024-01-05T06:00:00+00:00"
```

When i am executing the Test case i am facing the unparse exception, but if i try with the releatime code i dont see any issues, it works perfect in conversion

Comment: The input date "2024-01-05T06:00:00" does not contain a timezone in the string and when I remove "ZZZZZ" from your pattern your code works fine. This is understandable since the pattern does not actually match your input. Are you sure your input in the real case is the same as your tests? Is there a chance it contains a timezone?

Comment: Yes i am sure, the input is same in both via application and test case, input is "2024-01-05T06:00:00"
Event after i am removing and running the test case, i get the case fail as below
expected:<Fri Jan 05 11:30:00 IST 2024> but was:<Fri Jan 05 11:30:00 GMT+05:30 2024>
Expected :Fri Jan 05 11:30:00 IST 2024
Actual   :Fri Jan 05 11:30:00 GMT+05:30 2024